# C# Program crashes when Writing using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

It works only when the file is already created. When i delete the file and start from scratch it gives the following error

Code:

```
    private void Btn_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/"+ "File.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.CreateText(path);
            MessageBox.Show("File Created Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Already Created");
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("File.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }     
    }

    private void Btn_Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("File.txt"))
        {
            string text = sr.ReadLine();
            Text_Show.Text = text;
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(File.Exists("File.txt"))
        {
            File.Delete("File.txt");
            MessageBox.Show("File Deleted");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the full text of the exception?  What line is indicated in the stack trace?  `File.CreateText(path);` creates a file and opens a `StreamWriter` on the file.  You are not closing and disposing of this `StreamWriter` so it's possible that the file is locked when you try to later access with a `StreamReader`.

Comment: The error happen when you click the "Btn_Write" button?
We need more information.

Comment: File.CreateText(path); is intended to **return** an open file if you ignore the return value it will be open until GC happens.

Comment: Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'c:\users\dawood zaidi\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NotePad_App\NotePad_App\bin\Debug\File.txt' because it is being used by another process. But i dont think i have it opened somewhere else. After what line do i close it? Sorry for being a Noob :3

Comment: Yes @Cedric After i click the Write Button

Comment: But the thing is If the file is already created it would read it quite easily without showing the Exception @Chris Dunaway

Comment: didnt follow you mate. @MarcGravell

Comment: @Dawood it doesn't just *create* the file - it creates it **as an open file** and hands you back a reference to it, expecting you to write things and then close/dispose it. If you don't do that, then you've just left an open file dangling in mid air. It will get closed when GC notices that nothing can reach it, and finalises the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is inside your `Btn_Create_Click`. You are using `File.CreateText` without disposing the stream. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Just call `Dispose` or just place it inside a `Using`.

Like so:

```
private void Btn_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/"+ "File.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.CreateText(path).Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("File Created Successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File Already Created");
    }
}
```

Comment: @DawoodZaidi Did my answer fix your issue ?

Comment: @Dawood, you thank people by clicking the green checkmar to the upper left of the answer.